# restore password in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, passwords, sudo

I'm learning UBUNTU.
I'm using virtual box with ubuntu image, i created my user name as joe no password.
now that i try to execute any command that requires the sudo stuff it asks me for a password...this is weird because i didn't specify any password when loading the image into virtual box...is there a way to restore/reinitialize this password, i need it very bad for my homework, thanks guys

Comment: Since I don't think I can answer this any better than the answers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006 ... use that link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by booting  into `single user` mode and using root to change the password for the user `joe`. Edit the boot instructions for the GRUB menu entry you wish to boot and add the kernel parameter/option `single`.

1. Select (highlight) the GRUB boot menu entry you wish to use.
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the GRUB boot commands for the selected boot menu entry.
3. Look near the bottom of the list of commands for lines similar to

   `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=bc6f8146-1523-46a6-8b\`

   `6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash`

   `initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic`
4. Change the middle line in (3) by adding the kernel boot parameter `single` to the end of the line (i.e. after `ro  quiet splash`).

   For this example you would change

   `6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash` 

   to 

   `6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash single`
5. Press either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot using
   these kernel options.

After this you will be thrown into a shell. Enter `mount -o remount,rw /` then the command `passwd joe` and enter your new password for `joe`. Restart with `reboot` or `shutdown -r now`.

Comment: I may be missing something, but wouldn't you also have to `-o remount,rw` the root partition? How else would `passwd` write to the `/etc/shadow` file?

Comment: You're right. I believe Ubuntu tells you the command to write to mount the correct drive as soon as you're thrown into the shell.

Answer (score 1):

If account `joe` is just passwordless, `joe` can just log in and run `passwd` to give the account a new password.